# How to trigger jQuery behaviour on click or pressing enter on typeahead.js search results?

Tags: jquery, onclick, keypress, typeahead.js

I have a autocomplete search field ([typeahead.js](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/)) and I have a behaviour triggered when clicking on a search suggestion ie `on click`.

I would like the same behaviour triggered when arrowing down and pressing enter on a suggestion.

So I would like the behaviour to occur `on click` or `on pressing enter`.

In the example below, I use an input field rather than replicating the full typeahead.js search scenario.

The problem with the code below is that it is only triggered when pressing enter in the input field (because of the conditional attached to `e`) and not `on click`.

**HTML**

```
<input class="hello" value="hello">
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).on("click keypress",".hello", function (e) {
if (e.which == 13) {
alert($(this).val());
}
});
```

**jsFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/9xhK3/

**Edit:**

Updated jsFiddle with typeahead code:

http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/9xhK3/10/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trigger an event on \`click\` and \`enter\`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9146651/trigger-an-event-on-click-and-enter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

After seeing this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18710896/1063287

this code:

http://codepen.io/Sinetheta/pen/eAwcl

and this resource:

https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/300

```
function searchFunction() {
$('.my_class .typeahead').typeahead({                              
name: 'my_name',
valueKey: 'my_key',  
prefetch: 'path/to/json.json',
template: [
'<p class="key1">[[key_1]]</p>',
'<p class="my_key">[[my_key]]</p>',
'<p class="key3">[[key_3]]</p>'
].join(''),
engine: Hogan  
}).on('typeahead:selected', function(event, selection) {
var my_key = selection.my_key;
alert(my_key);
});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need to find the event type and just `or` it

```
$(document).on("click keypress",".hello", function (e) {
    if(e.which == 13 || e.type == "click") {
       alert($(this).val());
    }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working with `typeahead.js`, see updated jsFiddle with included typeahead code:  http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/9xhK3/10/

Comment: This does not work unfortunately - goals are to 1) alert when clicking on suggestion 2) alert when, after entering some text, arrowing down and pressing enter on suggestion.