# Bootstrap 4 Typeahead

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm using [jQuery Bootstrap Typeahead](https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Bootstrap-4-Typeahead-Plugin.html). I get data from my file but typeahead dropdown is not populate/shown.

Here is my JS:

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    var $input = $('.typeahead');

    $('.typeahead').typeahead({
        source: function (query, process) {
            return $.getJSON(
                'url-to-file.php',
                { query: query },
                function (data) {
                    console.log(data)
                    return process(data);
                })
        }
    });

})();
```

`console.log()` returns a (correct) JSON array:

```
[ "item1", "item2", ... ]
```

But I don't know what to do after. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data source should be...

```
[{name:"item1","id":"1"},{name:"item2","id":"2"},etc..]
```

And then use `data-provide` on an input like this...

```
   <div class="input-group">
       <input type="text" data-provide="typeahead" class="form-control typeahead border-primary" name="query" id="query" placeholder="search..." autocomplete="off">
   </div>
```

[Working Demo on Codeply](https://www.codeply.com/go/706TNx84a8/bootstrap-4-typeahead)

---

***Edit:*** You can also use a **simple string array**:
https://www.codeply.com/go/knBpcbhlFE

Comment: Actually your example works fine, but it loads the json data directly. My goal is that each time the user press key, a query is done in my database searching for the query and "then" return the json data. I'm ok with that but after I don't know how to inject/populate the dropdown list.

Comment: That would basically work the same as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18710325/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead-custom-keypress-enter-function

Comment: booth codeply examples doesnt work for me in FireFox (65.0.5) but works in Chrome

Comment: The links work for me, and besides the relevant code is in the answer too. Why did you downvote this? @SergeyRomanov

Comment: Because all links ave me 404 at that time like example is not there anymore. Now all works fine. I wanted to upvote but it does not let me until a post is edited. Sorry. Most probably that was so a problem with a codeply. Because 404 error was not a browser but their. Styles as codeply not found repo.